# Implicit main() in Java IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

I have created small Java project in IntelliJ with maven, including test classes (JUnit5) and the code runs and objects are created despite that I didn't code `main()` method and I can't find one. How is it possible that code runs without declaring `main()` method? Is the `main()` method implicitly declared by IDE in the background?

Comment: Is stuff running when you click on the green arrow for a JUnit test? That's one of IntelliJ's best features, in my opinion. If I had to choose between that and the over-the-top auto-complete, I'd take the individual test runner. Anyway, it's probably the JUnit test runner's `main()`.

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ has a plugin that will detect implementations of JUnit and execute your unit tests behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

To run JUnit main() method is not required. JUnits can be written to test individual method, passing expected parameters and checking method behavior. It is more like a method call than running the application.